# pdf page number font color using addwatermarkfromtext

Tags: vba, pdf, fonts, colors

I have a question regarding inserting page numbers in a pdf file using addwatermarkfromtext but at the same time change the font color of the page number. I am using the following code to insert the page number and that is working very well. Searching the internet I should be able to insert a line with "aColor:=color.red" but that is not working and the code will return an error. Does anyone know how to change the standard font color (black) to another color??

```
for i=1 to 10
jso.addWatermarkFromText _
            cText:=Str(i) , _
            cFont:="Arial", _
            nFontSize:=9, _
            nTextAlign:=1, _
            nHorizAlign:=2, _
            nVertAlign:=4, _
            nVertValue:=24, _
            nHorizValue:=-48, _
            nStart:=i - 1, _
            nEnd:=i - 1
next i
```

Thanks!

Comment: What programming language are you using please? AFAIK the JSO route is for VBA but the := construct and 'next i' do not appear to be standard VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=JS_API_AcroJS.88.437.html&accessible=true) the format for color information is more complex than you suggest. It needs a color type then value. Quote:

> For example, the color red can be represented as ["RGB", 1, 0, 0]

So I guess you want something more like

```
aColor:=["RGB", 1, 0, 0]
```

But that may be for JavaScript. The equivalent in VBA would be something like:

```
dim color(0 to 3) as Variant 
color(0) = "RGB"
color(1) = 1#
color(2) = 0#
color(3) = 0#
```

then

```
aColor=color
```

Comment: I have tried that as well, but that also gives me an error - Run-time error 13': Type mismatch :(

Comment: Edited for VBA color array config. But see my question against your post  about what language you are using.